# Pulling details of hosted services in azure programatically

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

Is there any API or class that helps the user to programmatically pull the details of hosted services in azure if user key-in's subscription id.

I could do the above with references you guys referred.

IS there any possibility to get Subscription details like subscription Name using Windows Azure API's

Comment: Thanks guys... One more thing is I'm getting all the details except details about the environment(i.e., whether it is hosted in Staging /production). What I found was to separately query to find out which are in production and staging. Is that only the way or am I missing any thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need both subscription id and the management certificate from the user. Once you have these two things, you could use Windows Azure Service Management REST API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx to get details about the hosted services.

Comment: Thanks guys... One more thing is I'm getting all the details except details about the environment(i.e., whether it is hosted in Staging /production). What I found was to separately query to find out which are in production and staging. Is that only the way or am I missing any thing

Comment: For this you would need to send request for each hosted service separately. Take a look at this link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460806.aspx

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [Service Management REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx)

for security reasons, it's not going to be as easy as entering a subscription id though.